# Databinding show index with item name in recylerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I'm new to databinding in android and I'm trying to load a recyclerview with some items. Suppose I've a list of items and I want to display the item name along with an index number which auto increments.

I know how to show the item name, but I'm stuck on how to show the index number which auto increments.
This is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="ean"
            type="com.xpetize.smartshop.models.EAN" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            bind:contentPadding="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="10"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/index"
                    android:text="???????????????????"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <TextView
                    android:text="@{ean.itemName}"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:id="@+id/item_name"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="9"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: you mean the testview postion with text

Comment: @Amitpandey Yeah, index like 1.2.3.

Comment: why you required index? you can add member varible hold index value in EAN and parse over here like variable ean

Comment: @VasudevVyas Thanks I've figured it out

Comment: post your EAN Class here so i can help you

Comment: What you did can you tell me?

Comment: @VasudevVyas Thanks for your help. I figured it out

Comment: @VasudevVyas I passed index value from my adapter class and displayed it in my view

Comment: cool !! another way to display index

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you would need the index for inside the view itself. There are several ways to get the index in code when it matters.

However, you can simply add a variable to your xml like this:

```
<variable name="index" type="int"/>
```

> Then just set it in your adapter

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BindingHolder, position: Int) {
    val model = data[position]

    holder.binding.setVariable(bindingModelId, model)
    holder.binding.index = position

    setupRowClickHandler(holder, model, position)

    holder.binding.executePendingBindings()
}
```

> Then in your xml just use it.

```
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/index"
                android:text="@{index}"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```